# Prove integral is convex

Tags: derivatives, probability-distributions, definite-integrals, convex-analysis, integral-inequality

$X$ are an iid draw from $(-\infty, \infty)$ according to $F$ with mean $\mu$.  Further let $A = a(x, \theta)/\cos (\alpha)$ and $B = ((1- \cos(\alpha) - \sin (\alpha))\mu + \sin (\alpha)x)/\cos(\alpha)$, where $a(x,\theta)$ is determined by
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
1 - F(A-B) = f(A-B)A.
\end{equation}
It is assumed that that $F$ has an increasing hazard rate, so there is a unique solution.  Note that both $A$ and $B$ are functions of $x$ and $\alpha \in [0,\pi/2]$. Show that the following integral is convex:
\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(1-F(A-B))A \cos(\alpha)dF(x)
\end{equation}

> **Attempt**: The regular method of differenting the function twice does not work.  I thought it may have something to do with Brunn-Minkowski theorem